# Bill printing jobs

Tags: c++, windows-xp, hook, kiosk, printer-control-language

I'm looking for a way to hook up all printing jobs on a machine.

We have some Kiosk computers running windows XP, and we would like to allow customers to print. We would like to be able to catch the printing job, as it is sent to the printer, analyze it, show the user a dialog with the price for the printing and if he approves - send the job to the printer.

If he doesn't approve, the job must be canceled.

My first idea was to use a hook. But is there a hook for printing jobs? How is it used?

Someone also mentioned PCL (Printer Command Language), meaning us to write a wrapper for the local printer driver. How difficult is that? Where can i find a good tutorial for PCL?

What about PJL (Printer job language)?

The target language is c++.

Your input will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Summerbulb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get notified about new printer jobs using [`Win32_PrintJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As soon as the job is created, call [`Pause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it to suspend, show your GUI. If the client accepts the job, call [`Resume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to actually print the file.

See [Example: Receiving Event Notifications Through WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a C++ example which handles WMI notifications.

Comment: Some of my colleagues claim that WMI is very unreliable. Since we're dealing with billing, reliability is a must.

Comment: @summerbulb: I suggest to just test it instead of basing technical decisions on fear, uncertainity and doubt. I worked fine for me, but I don't claim that it's bug free (just like I won't claim that any software is bug free, except TeX maybe :-).

Comment: We've decided to go with the WMI. I'll let you know if we run into unreliability issues.